# Is there any problem with this query? why doesn't it work?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

```
  public ArrayList<String> getQuietPlaces(String lng, String lat) {
        ArrayList<String> quietPlaces = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String quietPlacesLocation = "SELECT (quietPlaceLongitude || \"/\" || quietPlaceLatitude) as locationCoordinates" +
                " FROM quietPlaces Where quietPlaceLongitude BETWEEN "
                 + lng +"-10 AND "
                 + lng + "+10 AND quietPlaceLatitude BETWEEN"
                + lat +"-10 AND "
                + lat + "+10";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(quietPlacesLocation, new String[]{lng, lat});

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String locationCoordinate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("locationCoordinates"));
                quietPlaces.add(locationCoordinate);
            }
        }
        return quietPlaces;
    }
```

The idea is to return all places that fall within Y axis by +10 or -10, and same for X axis. It does work on SQLBrowser, however might be declared differently on Android Studio. I'm new to this software.

Answer (score 0):

Since you concatenate the values of the variables `lng` and `lat` you must not pass them as the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()` where you must pass null.
Also there is no need for using and escaping the double quotes if you enclose `/` inside single quotes:

```
String quietPlacesLocation = "SELECT (quietPlaceLongitude || '/' || quietPlaceLatitude) as locationCoordinates" +
        " FROM quietPlaces Where quietPlaceLongitude BETWEEN "
        + lng + "-10 AND "
        + lng + "+10 AND quietPlaceLatitude BETWEEN "
        + lat + "-10 AND "
        + lat + "+10";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(quietPlacesLocation, null);
```

But the recommended way for passing the parameters `lng` and `lat` is by using `?` placeholders and passing their values (4 values in your case) as the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()` like this:

```
String quietPlacesLocation = "SELECT (quietPlaceLongitude || '/' || quietPlaceLatitude) as locationCoordinates" +
        " FROM quietPlaces Where quietPlaceLongitude BETWEEN "
        + ? + "-10 AND "
        + ? + "+10 AND quietPlaceLatitude BETWEEN "
        + ? + "-10 AND "
        + ? + "+10";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(quietPlacesLocation, new String[] {lng, lng, lat, lat});
```